# cd inside a windows cmd, how to get back to original directory?

Tags: windows, cmd, local, cd

I am cd ing to a directory inside a windows .cmd file, but this file has various return points,

how do I make return to the original directory without saving the original directory and returning to it explicitly at every return point in the script.

I think is has something to do with scope....?

Answer (score 3):

Use PUSHD and POPD.

```
C:
CD \
PUSHD C:\Windows
POPD
```

Comment: @Erik, @David: I think the OP knows about `PUSHD` and `POPD`. Their problem is that the script they run has many exit points, so `POPD` would have to be added to every one of them.

Comment: http://stackapps.com/questions/345/stackguru-a-near-realtime-bot-for-all-stackexchange-sites

Comment: @Jon: He can still use PUSHD and POPD e.g. in a wrapper script

Comment: @Erik: Which brings us to my answer ;)

Answer (score 2):

Just add another level of indirection. Instead of `original_script.cmd`, run this:

```
PUSHD
CALL original_script.cmd
POPD
```